# Training Manual 2.8 and exercise data differences

Tags: qgis, training

I am a new user and trying to teach myself about QGIS using the 2.8 Training Manual and the training_manual_exercise_data downloaded from QGIS.

I am using the PDF of the manual, which seems to be consistent with the on-line version.

But even with the very first exercise the shp file it ask you to load have different names or some don't exist. There are no files available called Rivers or Buildings, and the ones there have _335 suffixes to the names. Okay, I can work round this, but the examples are then different.

The next stage is to load landuse.sqlite, which does not appear to exist in the exercise data at all.

So I am wondering if there is a different set of exercise data that is the one I should be using.

Comment: [landuse.sqlite](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/blob/master/source/docs/training_manual/exercise_data/epsg4326/landuse.sqlite)

Comment: The paths in example.qgs seem to be wrong https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/blob/master/source/docs/training_manual/exercise_data/example.qgs